CSS combinator for same element or descendants
Is there a CSS selector combinator for selecting two classes in the same element or in any descendant. For example:
<div class="theme-classic btn"></div>

or:
<div class="theme-classic">
  <div>
    <div class="btn"></div>
  </div>
</div>

If in my CSS file I write: .theme-classic.btn I do not select the descendants.
If in my CSS file I write: .theme-classic .btn I do not select the first case where the classes are on the same element.
Of course, I can do something like:
.theme-classic.btn,
.theme-classic .btn { ... }


But I can't find a combinator that does both.

In CSS, there isn't a single combinator that directly selects elements with two specific classes, whether they are on the same element or in any descendant. However, you can achieve this by using multiple selectors separated by a comma, as you've already mentioned. This is the correct approach:
css
Copy code
.theme-classic.btn,
.theme-classic .btn {
/* Styles */
}

@AmmadHassan OK, thank you. I'm surprised that such combinator does not exists, but OK

As per my knowledge and little research I don't know any combinators that you want
May be any other member knows any trick or hack related to this

Your last example is the correct way to do it

Actually it doesn't make much sense to have this what you call "combinator". If you have multiple elements sharing the same styles you should better create a class having all the properties the elements share and assign that class to all those elements. Why would you set absolutely the same styles to different classes and assign them both?

This does not exist in CSS.
You need to select them both separately like you mentioned:
.theme-classic.btn,
.theme-classic .btn { 
    ... 
}


CSS nesting can help you simplify the selector and avoid repeating .theme-classic


.theme-classic {
   :is(& .btn,&.btn) {
     color: red;
   }
}
<div class="theme-classic btn">Select</div>
<div class="theme-classic"> Don't select</div>
<div class="btn"> Don't select</div>
<div class="theme-classic">
  <div>
    <div class="btn">Select</div>
    <div >Don't Select</div>
  </div>
</div>



